# How do I set an environment variable for sudo in MacOS?

Tags: bash, environment-variables

I have installed ServiceMix on my machine, and am trying to start it. The startup script is called start.sh. When I did `./start.sh`, it gave me a Permission Denied message. So I used `sudo ./start.sh`, which starts the server fine.

However, it seems to be using Java 7, when I would like to use Java 6 (for various reasons). I looked through the start.sh script and found that it uses the `JAVA_HOME` variable. So I set my JAVA_HOME to the JDK 6 directory.

However, ServiceMix still uses Java 7.

A Google search revealed that when a command is run with sudo, sudo removes certain environment variables. So I did `sudo -E ./start.sh`. Again, it used JDK 7.

I opened the start.sh and added a line, `echo $JAVA_HOME` to see whether the variable is set properly or not. The output of `echo` was an empty line.

I tried modifying the /etc/sudoers file to include `Defaults env_keep += "JAVA_HOME"`. Executing start.sh now tells me that my echo statement is again an empty line. ServiceMix still uses JDK 7.

I tried setting JAVA_HOME in `/etc/profile`. Executing start.sh now tells me that my echo statement is again an empty line. Again, ServiceMix uses JDK 7.

What mistake am I doing here?

FWIW, am on Mac OS X 10.8.2. `echo $SHELL` on my terminal returns /bin/bash. When I use `sudo su` and fire `echo $SHELL`, it returns /bin/sh.

Comment: Why not just set JAVA_HOME explicitly in start.sh?

Comment: Why not sudo chmod the start.sh file so that the program can run at user-level privileges

Comment: Did you `export JAVA_HOME`? If it's not an _environment_ variable, `sudo -E` won't keep it.

Comment: I don't know for sure, but also try `export JRE_HOME=$JAVA_HOME`

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to try out the following steps:

1. Inside `/etc/profile.d` directory, create a file named `set_java_path.sh` file containing the line

   `export JAVA_HOME=<_complete_path_to_java6_directory_>`
2. Run `bash` command once to make the above change to load. And run the `start.sh` script.

**Edit:**

If the `/etc/profile.d` directory doesn't exist, create a directory names same (permission: 0755 & owner and group as root) and inside your `/etc/profile` file, add the following code:

```
if [ -d /etc/profile.d ]; then
  for i in /etc/profile.d/*.sh; do
    if [ -r $i ]; then
      . $i
    fi
  done
  unset i
fi
```

Comment: I don't seem to have a /etc/profile.d directory. Should I create it?

Comment: @ShivasubramanianA: I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

To preserve your environment variables as sudoer add `Defaults env_keep += PATH` to your sudoer file (`sudo visudo`).

Comment: i upvoted for the intent of the answer, and because I learned something new.  note that OP is asking about JAVA_HOME, not PATH, though that's trivial and the answer would be the same.